# Recording acoustic guitar with Zoom H4

Tags: microphone

I've been trying some recording of my acoustic with the H4. I was playing fingerstyle, so not as loud as when using a pick/plectrum. [This recording](http://soundcloud.com/steevc/empty-spaces) was with the H4 on a tripod just next to my hand (neck side). It's picking up a lot of fretting hand noise and there's a fair bit of variation in level as some notes just ring out louder.

Any suggestions on how to get the best from this set-up? Would any of the H4 effects or mic models be worth using?

BTW I'm using a Dean Performer E guitar. This has a pickup which I need to try some time. I'm wondering if it's worth mixing the pickup with a mic recording, but that would mean getting a mic I can plug into the H4 as you can't use the internal mics with the inputs at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The H4 comes with an XY-style stereo microphone system, which can be quite a thrill to record an acoustic guitar with, provided that the device is placed at the correct angle and distance.

As a start, try pointing the device to the guitar just above the hole, at the end of the fingerboard. Depending on acoustics and the amount of stereo separation, vary the distance between the device and the instrument. Attach the device to some kind of stand to make the position perfect.

If you are getting too much fret noise, rather than moving the device away from it, tilt the device away from it, i.e. point the microphone end a bit more towards the bottom of the guitar. The XY microphones in the H4 are cardioid, that means they are less sensitive on the side than they are on the front.